# Mountain bike freewheel replacement

Tags: mountain-bike, freewheel

My freewheel pawls recently shattered and I was wondering if the new one I am about to order will work.

[image: My old freewheel]

[New freewheel at ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Sunrace-MF-M05-Multi-Speed-5-Speed-Freewheel-Sprocket-14-28T-Black-5sp-Threaded/302337272460)

[image: From ebay auction]

The only difference I noticed was the new sprocket is more spread out.

Comment: The small cog is severely worn.  No doubt your chain is similarly worn and will need to be replaced along with the freewheel.

Comment: Ya I read that on a fourm post I plan on picking one up

Comment: Both appear to be 14-28 tooth, so it should be a straightforward swap.  The only specialist tool you need is a freewheel remover, like the *Park FR-1.2* or similar.  And a bench vise or a large spanner.

Comment: Sadly 14 tooth is the smallest small cog you're likely to find on a freewheel due to the dimensions.  If you're spending a lot of time in that top (small rear/big front) gear then it may be worth considering some higher gears (smaller cogs) by switching to a cassette-based wheel, capable of going down to 11 tooth.  Depends if you're happy in your current gear or if you want to go faster for the same cadence.

Comment: I was searching for this same part for my kids bike that i want to sell.  I didn't have the removal tool nor did I want to buy it since I have no other freewheel bikes.  My LBS replaced the freewheel for $12 installed.  Couldn't beat that price anywhere, I'm glad I stopped by.

Answer (score 2):

The new freewheel looks like a drop in replacement. Both are 5 speed 14-28 teeth. Removal tool splines are the same so you can use the tool you presumably have.

Not sure what you mean by 'spread out'. Sprocket spacing and tooth pitch are all standardized in the bicycle world so a sprocket with the same number of teeth will be functionally equivalent.

Comment: By spread out I mean the last row of teeth is larger then the second to last to where there's an actual gap able to be seen while my original. Has very little to no gaps when looking at the same angle. It probably makes no difference and I'm just over worrying it

Comment: @Ragekillen I think that is because the new unit has bigger cut-outs in the largest sprocket.

Comment: So no real difference that make it unusable, I ordered it. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: I think the new one has less metal in the back, for weight savings.  Its functionally identical.